# Remove strings between brackets and the bracket itself

Tags: regex

I have this data:

```
<div><b>CANADA INC.</b></div>
```

I want to remove everything between `<>` and the `<>` itself.

I want it to look like:

```
CANADA INC.
```

Can I use RegEx to do the trick?

Comment: Remove `<[^>]*>` from your string

Comment: Do you have anything that looks like `<a href="thing>otherthing">` in your data? Or `<button onclick="pushbutton(value > value2)">`? Because if so, the solution changes drastically

Comment: I am a newbie, I am using Openrefine to clean dataset.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that you should not really use RegEx to parse HTML. You should see if the language you are using supports parsing HTML, or maybe find a plugin to so do it.

Now we have that over and done with, there are 2 ways of doing this:

### Method 1

```
<[^>]*>
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3vq)</kbd>

How it works:

```
<        # Opening <
[^>]*    # Any character except a > any number of times
>        # Closing >
```

---

### Method 2

```
<.*?>
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3vt)</kbd>

How it works:

```
<        # Opening <
.*       # Any character any number of times
?        # Make sure the expression is not greedy (and select the entire string)
>        # Closing >
```

Comment: Actually, they're both equivalent, as far as I can tell. And both have the same shortcoming of not actually supporting everything HTML does, but that's just because a standards-compliant regex to remove HTML would end up shockingly complicated, probably.

Comment: Actually, they probably are. I just tested a few different combos on RegExr, I'll update my answer. Thanks!